# Display controller name in small case in url + Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to display controller name in small case in url in Zend Framework

Ex :

```
AlbumController.php
```

and I am using the following url:

```
<a href='/Album/'>album</a>
```

It is displaying Album name as "`Album`" as it is in url while I want to display it like "`album`" in to the url. Also I want to keep "`Album`" as it is in href tag.

How should I do this.

Please help me....thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just making the URL lowercase? I'm fairly certain that using the default route for Zend Framework, the controller name is case insensitive. <del>The action name is not however.</del> If you camel case the action name, it [changes the expected view script](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration.render).

**Update**: Perhaps you just mean the url is title case while the link itself is not. If that's the case, just make the url lowercase:

```
<a href='/album/'>album</a>
```

Comment: If i am passing controller name in lower case in href like  `<a href='/Album/'>album</a>`
then it showing me it in lower case in url but problem is it redirecting me in same action instead of desired action.

Comment: If you mean that on the page the text is lowercase (it's 'album'), but when followed the resulting URL in the address bar is title case (it's 'Album') - that what would be expected from your HTML. Just change the URL in the link to be lowercase (as in my update).

Comment: If I used like this : `<a href='/album/'>album</a>` then it's giving me redirection problem. See my question related to this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158045/small-case-controller-name-in-url-not-working-in-zend-framework#comment17904291_13158045

Comment: I doubt your issues are actually with the case.

Comment: actually, I am not able to understand how its happening...but one thing sure I want url in lowercase but these issues are coming

Answer (score 1):

You may get the controller name from the Request object when being inside the controller

```
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Or access it globally

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

However, the best way to do this is using the "url" view helper in any view.

```
$this->url(array("module" => "default", "controller" => "album", "action" => "index"), "default");
```

The "module" parameter is optional. The second parameter "default" is the route to be used to build a reverse link, it is also optional. When using custom routes, make sure you define the "reverse" property of the route, ex.:

```
resources.router.routes.recipe_view.reverse = "recipes/%d-%s"
```

For more about routes configuration, see [here](http://www.iostream.eu/zend-framework-application-ini-cheat-sheet/)
For more view helpers, see [here](http://www.iostream.eu/zend-framework-cheat-sheet/)